# How to allow only one file in Apache

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

I have a bootstrap file which is `index.php` and I only allow this page to be called by people not other ones.

I've come up with the code below and I received an Internal 500 error. I like to show the log files but I cannot since I am running this on the shared hosting but what I know is it is CGI mode.

I put that code in `.htaccess`and received error and put it in `php.ini` and didn't work.

```
<File /index.php>
  Allow from all
  Require None
  Satisfy Any
</File>
```

What's I am doing wrong?

Comment: So basically everything will be processed by the index.php file?

Comment: @BookOfZeus: Yes, only index.php will take care of stuff and other files are only includes with the extension .php (not .inc)

Comment: You have other rules in your .htaccess file or vhost file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is just redirect all requests to the `index.php` file and let the index file handle any bad requests, since it already handles all the friendly URL requests and everything. This way you don't really need extra code in the index file. It will run normally and see 'somefile.php' and the page they're trying to open and determine that this is not a valid page to be opening and error out like any other invalid path, at least it would for the way mine is set up.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

You would have to exclude any images or CSS folders if you don't use sub-domains for them like I do, or you can process them with the index file as well.

Example for excluding images and css folders:

```
RewriteRule !^(images|css)/.* index.php [L]
```

Or if you don't want to do that, you could send all the disallowed files to `-`.

```
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|images/.*|css/.*) - [L]
```

Comment: I'm using the same technique. And is there `File` directive in apache config? In [list of directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html) there is no the one.